# Integrated Webcam gets detected but not working on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: kernel, video, webcam, 20.10

So after the update to Ubuntu 20.10 from 18.04.2 LTS, My webcam stopped working. When I try `cheese` or `uvcvideo` it opens for a few times with flickering and goes blank. Now, this issues goes way back to 2011 and keeps popping up intermittently with kernel updates. I went through all the suggestions and questions marked solved pertaining to this issue but notwithstanding the solution to my problem. opening the similar question here is last hail mary attempt to address my problem. Please advice.

`dmesg | grep uvc`

````
[ 2997.130632] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 2997.134635] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 2997.138636] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 2997.142634] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 2997.146635] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).```
````

Comment: it seems this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed/+bug/1881757  comes back.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have shown output for the diagnostic message using `dmesg` command. uvcvideo is a driver for the camera. so whenever I start the cheese or uvc client to run camera it throws these as error for `dmseg` in the console.

Comment: Please add more details on your system